# How to update values in a nested dictionary using values from another nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

New to the Stackoverflow, apologies if the title isn't that clear.

Effectively I am working with two xl to CSV files, both converted into nested dictionaries using method `to_dict`, where index is the key for the each (main?) dictionary and the columns are the keys for each nested dictionary.

i.e.

```
 DICTA = {0: {x:1, y:2, v:3}, 1: {x:5, y:6, v:7}, 2: {x:8, y:9, v:10}}

 DICTB = {0: {a:3, b:12, c:13, d:14}, 1: {a:15, b:16, c:17, d:18}, 2: {a:19, b:20, c:21, d:22}}
```

Values are arbitrary for the example above (length of both dictionaries will always be the same, nested dictionaries have different number of keys)

Each nested dictionary in DICT B can only be used once to update a a nested DICT A dict i.e. each nested dict in DICT A 'belongs' to a nested dict in DICT B but not in any specific order.

My aim is to update values (of nested dicts) in Dict A with values from Dict B (keys are diff for both) if other conditions/values are met.. i.e. what I have so far:

```
for k, v in DICTA.items():
i=0
h=0
  if DICTA[i].get('v') in (DICTB[h].get('a'), (DICTB[h].get('b')):
    if (DICTB[h].get('a') != '15': #another condition I need to put in
        DICTA[i].update({'x': DICTB[h].get('c')}) 
        DICTA[i].update({'y': DICTB[h].get('d')})
        i+=1 
    else:
        DICTA[i].update({'y': DICTB[h].get('c')}) 
        DICTA[i].update({'x': DICTB[h].get('d')})
        i+=1
  else:
      h+=1
```

Actual output:

```
In: DICTA

Out: {0: {x:13, y:14, v:3}, 1: {x:5, y:6, v:7}, 2: {x:8, y:9, v:10}}
```

Expected Output for the above:

```
In: DICTA

Out: {0: {x:13, y:14, v:3}, 1: {x:18, y:17, v:7}, 2: {x:21, y:22, v:10}}
```

My issue is that this works for the first DICTA entry but then fails to update the next two i.e. this clearly doesn't update i or h correctly to loop through the next nested dictionary.

Fully aware the above might be painfully un-pythonic and am very much open to easier ways of solving this.

Thanks guys appreciate any help with the above.

Comment: It's not very clear what the condition is. And also, please fix your indentation and syntax errors first.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't post the exact code as it contains some sensitive data so had to replicate it with the example code - will update. I am effectively trying to loop through DICT A nested dictionaries and and update them with values from DICT B nested dictionaries. I am not sure how to specify this loop to move onto the next nested dictionary in DICT A and check the same conditions before updating or moving on.

Comment: Could you also provide what output you'd expect to get in your example?

Comment: Updated with output expected. Also added for clarity: Each nested dictionary in DICT B can only be used once to update a nested DICT A dict i.e. each nested dict in DICT A 'belongs' to a single nested dict in DICT B but not in any specific order.

Comment: And added actual output.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly this should work:

```
for row_a, row_b in zip(DICTA.values(), DICTB.values()):
    if row_a.get('v') in (row_b.get('a'), row_b.get('b')):
        if row_b.get('a') != '15':
            row_a.update({
                'x': row_b.get('c'), 
                'y': row_b.get('d')
            })
        else:
            row_a.update({
                'y': row_b.get('c'), 
                'x': row_b.get('d')
            })
```

Also instead of:

```
row_a.update({
    'x': row_b.get('c'), 
    'y': row_b.get('d')
})
```

You could use:

```
row_a['x'] = row_b.get('c')
row_a['y'] = row_b.get('d')
```

but that's a question of preference.

Comment: Hmm I think this would work if the nested dictionary were ordered i.e. Index 1 in DICTA is mapped to Index 1 DICTB and so on... there may be occasions were     if row_a.get('v') in (row_b.get('a'), row_b.get('b')): this condition is not met and I would be need to try the next nested dict in DICTB

Comment: Actually this also seems to only pick up the last nested dictionary values as row_b and row_a:                                                                                                                                      In [7]:row_a
Out[8]: {'x': 8, 'y': 9, 'v': 10}

row_b
Out[9]: {'a': 19, 'b': 20, 'c': 21, 'd': 22}